# Icons not showing on sudo dolphin on 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin, plasma-5

Greetings again everyone, I update my system recently from 15.04 to 15.10. And among the many bizarre errors, when I open dolphin as root, by using `kdesudo dolphin`, no icons load. They do load normally on dolphin but not as root.

EDIT: Another error happened now, I tried navigating on the elevated dolphin and this error popped.

[image: Error when trying to navigate]

[image: Icons showing normally when running dolphin]

[image: No icons when escalated as root]

Comment: IIRC, it's also not showing icons if started in an openbox session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of the ops issue is [a known bug in KDE](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353263) affecting any application running under `sudo`.

The recommended work around is to

1. Open Konsole and enter the following commands to edit the sudoers file:

   ```
   sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/workaround_kde5
   ```
2. In the appearing editor add the line:

   ```
   Defaults env_keep += "KDE_SESSION_VERSION KDE_FULL_SESSION"
   ```
3. Save and exit the editor.

For reasons unknown to the commenter these variables are required for proper icon loading. `sudo`/`su` strips them by default this line tells it not to.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got icons working by installing the full `kubuntu-desktop` package, restarting, and logging into plasma once.

Logging out and back into gnome3 gave me a few icons.

Interestingly enough, dolphin4 gives all icons as expected, it's just the QT5 build of dolphin that doesn't have icons, (and consequently any package compiled with QT5 instead of Qt4 misbehaves).

Answer (score 0):

There is solution in kubuntuforums:
 [Application that installs "access to root in dolphin menu"](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/archive/index.php/t-68742.html)

> by kubicle:   Anybody get Kubicles Root Action to work with 15.10? It
>   works on 15.10, but with kf5-dolphin, you need to tinker a bit:
>
> 1. Copy the menu's two .desktop files ("10-rootactionsfolders.desktop" and "11-rootactionsfiles.desktop")
>      from "~/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/" to
>      "~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/" (The new location for kf5)
> 2. if there is no "/usr/share/kservicetypes5/konqpopupmenuplugin.desktop" file
>      installed, link the kde4 version of konqpopupmenuplugin with:   Code:
>      `sudo ln -s /usr/share/kde4/servicetypes/konqpopupmenuplugin.desktop
>      /usr/share/kservicetypes5/konqpopupmenuplugin.desktop`
>      (This is a
>      general issue with kf5-dolphin and servicemenus, not directly related
>      to the root-actions-servicemenu)
> 3. restart dolphin

Answer (score 0):

Try launching it with `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=kde`:

```
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=kde
kdesudo dolphin
```